# open recent created folder in c# code

Tags: c#

I want to open recently created folders with c # code.

However, the folder name changes each time,

so I need to access it based on the most recently created time.

I've looked at many other examples, but I have not got a satisfactory answer.

I'd appreciate it if you could give me a solution.

Comment: Looks like there's a `CreationTime` property on `DirectoryInfo`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx  Have you tried using that?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried 
 var lastDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\cazador7\Desktop\SJ").GetDirectories("*",
   SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTimeUtc).First();

it works but This code only fetches the value , does not open it. I try process.start(lastDirectory); but it didn't work. how can I open recent directory?

Comment: What does "open recent directory" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the given path you can find last created directory as follows:

```
var lastDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories("*",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTimeUtc).First();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer
it works but
This code only fetches the value , does not open it.
I try process.start(lastDirectory);
but it didn't work.
how can I open recent directory?

Comment: @민성준 Use this:  Process.Start(lastDirectory.FullName);